# htaccess redirect except backend

Tags: backend, redirect, exception, .htaccess

We are running a magento installatino with two websites. I have configured a .htaccess redirect with GeoIP in order to redirect visitors from one country to website number two.

This works, however the backend url gets also redirected which would not be a problem, but it makes the backend behave "strange" like searches and saving don't work anymore.

Here is what I put into the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^website\.co.th$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^TH$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.co.th/$1 [L]
```

What would I have to add in order to exempt the backend from the redirect rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem:

First answer in this thread works for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502026/htaccess-rewrite-folder-exception